# Getting jest to run a single file

Tags: jestjs

How do i get jest to run a single file? I give `jest path/to/tests.js` but one of `testMatch` and `testRegex` seems to make jest ignore the file. I even made `testMatch` and `testRegex` hardcoded to the file name but that did not work.

Comment: Show us your testMatch and testRegex, please!

Comment: testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 54 matches

Answer (score 1):

Try running `jest` with the path to the **test**, not the **source file**. Also ensure the test file ends in `.test.js`.

e.g.

```
jest tests/path/to/file.test.js
```

Comment: it was actually `tests.js`. Just edited the question

Comment: Oh... tried naming it index.test.js? That's the standard name usually.

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow Re-read the answer now

Comment: I'm aware i can just change the extension. But I am writing a test wrapper that takes a bunch of test files and produces the results.

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow change testMatch to not contain (spec|test) then